# How can I show information on the chart?

Tags: pine-script

how can i show this? I want to show this on the chart or in the input menu, basically it is a win and loss counter.

```
var contador_stop = 0
var contador_takeper= 0

if longStopLosshit
    contador_stop := +1
    contador_takeper:= -1

if longTPhit 
    contador_stop := -1
    contador_takeper:= +1
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display this in the input menu. You can use a table and display it on your chart.

Something like below:

```
var tbl = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 2, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id = tbl, column = 0, row = 0, text = "SL count: " + str.tostring(contador_stop))
    table.cell(table_id = tbl, column = 1, row = 0, text = "TP count: " + str.tostring(contador_takeper), bgcolor=color.teal)
```